# magento - differences with collections

Tags: magento

I'm starting to gain a little experience with magento but collections are are thrown up some inconsistencies.

1. Some collections use addAttributeToSelect and addAttributeToFilter whereas others use addFilter and addSelect.

Why is this and how do you tell straight off which collection uses which?

1. How the hell do you join collections. I've tried every single example out there which never works. Specifically I would like to join shipping, invoice and order collections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As far as I know there are no addFilter and addSelect functions in Magneto. What you might refer to is differences between `addFieldToFilter` and `addAttributeToFilter`.

   The difference between those two is that there is a specific data type in Magento called `EAV`. You can read more about it anywhere else. Products and their attributes, customers and sales are `EAV` in Magneto. The quick background under `EAV` is that the data is kept in a different tables that's why functions to filter a collection is absolutely different.
2. This brings us to your second questions. Since there is not single table for products, customers or orders in Magento you can't apply normal SQL `join` to it. However it's quite unlikely that you will need it often. For all other non-`EAV` cases you can use the following syntax:

   ```
   $collection = Mage::getModel('group/model')->getCollection();
   $collection->getSelect()->join(array(
       'your_alias' => Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('group2/model2')),
       'main_table.your_id = your_alias.your_id',
       array());
   ```

Please let me know if I can make it more clear.